# Is there a way to have text appear below absolute element without adding a margin-top to the element?

Tags: html, css

I am making a multi-list dropdown navigation, and below that I want some text or a photo to be displayed. Since my navbar has a position of absolute, the text is appearing behind the navbar rather than below it. Is there a way that I can get my text to appear below without using a margin or padding on the element or container beneath the nav?

Currently the "fix" that I have been using is to add a style of `margin-top: 4rem` or the same with padding to my h1 to get it to show under the nav rather than behind it.

Since I want to use this navigation bar on multiple pages though with differing content, I am hoping to not need to continuously find the element below the navigation and add that padding/margin to it. Is there any other way or do I just need to use the current "solution"?

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/oNNrqRX)

Snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #363636;
}
nav .nav-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
nav .third-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
nav .third-level-menu > li {
  height: auto;
  background: #414141;
}
nav .second-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 15rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1ch;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
nav .second-level-menu > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #474747;
  text-align: left;
}
nav .top-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}
nav .top-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 9.4rem;
  background: #363636;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
nav .top-level-menu a {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: block;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  
</header>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Wyoming</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Washington</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Washington</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Washington</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Idaho</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Minnesota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Duluth</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Montana</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>South Dakota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">SD</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SD</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>North Dakota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="sales.html">Sale</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
<h1>HELLO IS ANYONE THERE?</h1>
```

Comment: The short answer to your question is no because the absolute element is outside the document flow and as such does not take space with in it. There are other ways to compensate for this, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `div` with an `id` of 'navspace'. This will need to be added to every page underneath the nav.

Then I added a line of javascript which makes this `div` the same height as the `nav`. All other elements will therefore appear below the `nav`.

```js
document.getElementById("navspace").style.height = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #363636;
}

nav .nav-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

nav .third-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

nav .third-level-menu>li {
  height: auto;
  background: #414141;
}

nav .second-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 15rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1ch;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

nav .second-level-menu>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #474747;
  text-align: left;
}

nav .top-level-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

nav .top-level-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 9.4rem;
  background: #363636;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav .top-level-menu a {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: block;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .top-level-menu li:hover>ul {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

</header>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Wyoming</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wyoming li</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Washington</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Washington</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Washington</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Idaho</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho Falls</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Minnesota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Duluth</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Montana</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>South Dakota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">SD</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SD</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>North Dakota</a>
            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Idaho</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="sales.html">Sale</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ogden, UT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="navspace"></div>
<br>
<h1>HELLO IS ANYONE THERE?</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a cool fix. I ended up using the same DIV idea , but adding it below the nav. Then I set the height to the 4rem used for the nav and it accomplished the same thing. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Great! It might be that the javascript is unnecessary then, it is only necessary if the height of the nav is unknown and it is higher on some pages than on others..